# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString causing UI freeze

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uiwebview, grand-central-dispatch

I am calling JavaScript using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`. I have `UISlider` and other UI elements working simultaneously. My whole UI freezes when JavaScript call happens. I looked around about this and found out that making
the call asynchronous should solve the problem.

I have tried two approaches:

`[webView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) withObject:func waitUntilDone:NO]`

And this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                [webView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) withObject:func waitUntilDone:NO];

        });
```

But none of this seems to work. My UI still freezes for fraction of a second which is noticeable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:func];

});
```

Comment: same result.. still freezes.

Comment: then plz check your script,

Answer (score 0):

performSelectorOnMainThread: executes on main thread (The thread of UI).
I think error in your JavaScript, the script executes infinitely.